# how to disable date before today in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable dates before today.(i.e. say today's date is 04Oct17 and I would like all the dates before this disabled but still enabling user to go to previous months, years, etc.)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
     var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
     var options = { 
      format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
 };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
 })
```

Comment: add a `minDate: new Date()` in your `options` Obj.

Answer (score 0):

In your datepicker options add minDate

```
 var dateToday = new Date(); // Today's Date.
 var options = { 
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  container: container,
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  minDate:dateToday // <--- this will disable all date less then dateToday
 };
 date_input.datepicker(options);
```

Comment: Is `dateToday` a jQuery UI constant of some sort? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: It's a Date. You can use `minDate: new Date('1999/10/25')`